# How to configure Logitech VX Revolution's extra buttons (zoom slider, ect.)?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, mouse, button

Is there any way to make work my Logitech VX Revolution's extra buttons under Ubuntu 11.10? Under Ubuntu 9.10 I've found a graphical interface program that was suitable to configure the extra buttons, but forgot the package name. 
I'd like to use the zoom slider buttons for controlling system volume, the upper search button for mute.
Please inform me about how can I set these buttons for the required functions, or if there's any graphical interface program to configure with, that information would be nice too.

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the off chance that you're still looking, the "easygesture" software package seems to provide what you're looking for, and also working in 12.04.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll give it a try, and will post my experiences.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a keyboard.
I have logitech mouse and the G15 keyboard, anyway before the g15 I have a similar problems with my elite logitech keyboard, your have several utilities to set that keys that:

if the keys shows output on the xev (terminal) you can use xbindkeys

if not your need to add the keymods or use http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/ this utility

Comment: Keytouch! You're the man! That's what I forgot! Thank you very much, saved a lot of time for me!

Comment: But wait a minute, i just realized, this is just for keyboards? Is there any software with graphical interface for binding mouse keys?